# Tab bar disappears after segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uitabbar

**Update:**

i hope this helps.
a b c d are the buttons in the tabbar.
viewcontroller1 is segued by b --> no tabbar.
the same with viewcontroller2, which is segued from viewcontroller1

```
Tabbar Controller
     I
     I_____ a
     I
     I_____ b ---- viewcontoller1 
     I                   I
     I_____ c            I__viewcontroller2
     I
     I_____ d
```

Ive searched for solutions, but no approaches helped me.

In my app i have as initial view a tab bar controller.
this tab bar has 4 views.
I want to switch from one of these views to another view.

Therefore im using segues.
After presenting the destination view, there is no tabbar anymore.

In the storyboard im using adaptives segues --> show (e.g. push)

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
    self->takenImage = image;
    double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"OrtToBulldDetail" sender:self];

    });
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"OrtToBulldDetail"]){
        BuildDetailView *editViewController =
        (BuildDetailView *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [editViewController setMyImage:takenImage];
    }
}
```

I also tried to use a navigation controller, but the destination view was load twice and my status bar was overlayed from another statusbar..

so where does my tabbar go? How can i get it back?

Comment: Are you saying you're using a tab bar controller with 4 views, but you want to push/segue between each of the views in the tab bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use a navigation controller, then a "Show" segue presents the controller modally which covers the entire screen, including the tab bar. You should embed the b controller in a navigation controller, then the "Show" segue will do a push to viewcontroller1.

I_____  UINavigationController------b ---- viewcontoller1

Comment: Thank u rdelmar. After embedding b in a nav controller, do i have to change the code? Because the view controller isn't shown..

Comment: UPDATE: I have several issues:
view controller b uses an imagepickercontroller. I have to choose twice an image, to get to viewcontroller1 (if i choose an image the first time no segue). then view controller is load twice..