# Tab Bar Disappearing After a Segue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I looked at the following two resources:  [Tab bar disappears after segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27698195/tab-bar-disappears-after-segue) and [My Tab bar controller disappears after a push segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915930/my-tab-bar-controller-disappears-after-a-push-segue). However, both of them are in Objective-C and they don't seem to address the issue that I am having.

Here is my Main Story Board:

[image]

Zoomed in is:

[image]

Now, let's  call the view controller that has Sign Up and Log In VC1 and the one with the Facebook button, VC2. When I go to VC1 from the Tab Bar Controller, everything is good. I have the tab bar on the bottom of my VC1. And I tap `Sign Up` and the tab bar is gone. Which I want. And when I go back to VC1 (there is a navigation bar on VC2 with the button `cancel` that I programmatically added in, and when clicked on, takes me to VC1), the tab bar is gone. But I want the tab bar there.

Some people have suggested me to use a `navigation controller`. But I do not want to use it because I don't want the tab bar to appear when the user clicks on `Sign Up`. And, the navigation controller only allows for right to left and left to right segues and I want custom segues (I tried customizing the segues for a navigation controller and it caused a crash for me).

So my question is, does anybody know how to keep the tab bar on VC1 AFTER going to another View Controller WITHOUT a tab bar, and going back to VC1 WITH the tab bar?

Sorry for the long post.

Comment: have a look -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517047/tab-bar-after-login-why-does-it-look-like-this/36517380#36517380